# The cron job "Activity processor (Hourly)" fails

Tags: civievent, cron-job

The cron job "Activity processor (Hourly)" has started failing for no apparent reason with the message "Failure, Error message: Process Activities failed" in the job log, although the message coming from cron is "Failed Processing: . Reason: DB Error: syntax error". Neither message is much help.

We are running CiviCRM 4.5.8 under WordPress 4.2.2.

Has anyone experienced this? Where do I start to find and fix the problem?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on debugging (**Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**) you should get a more verbose error from cron, which should in turn allow you to troubleshoot - or at least update your question with more info!

Comment: It's possible your CiviCRM logfile (`CiviCRM.something.log` in `wp-content/plugins/files/`) already has a record of the SQL error happening in cron.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried to change the password of an email account, and the problem is solved. In the old password I had a question mark.